# How to use Regular Expression on lotus script?

Tags: javascript, lotusscript

My coding is in javascript, It is use check on Malaysian Identity Card No:

Sample Malaysian Identity Card : 901011-13-6725

```
    var MyIC = @Left(@Trim(document1.getValue("NRIC")),14)

        if(MYIC!=null)
        {

             var re = /([0-9][0-9])((0[1-9])|(1[0-2]))((0[1-9])|([1-2][0-9])|(3[0-1]))\-([0-9][0-9])\-([0-9][0-9][0-9][0-9])/;


            if (re.test(document1.getValue("NRIC"))) 
            {
               document1.setvalue("Comment", this is a valid NRIC)
            }
            else
            {
               document1.setvalue("Comment", this is not a valid NRIC)
            }
```

If i want to use lotus script to write regEx, got any method to do it?

Answer (score 4):

either have a look at the method "like" or see http://lekkimworld.com/2005/09/25/using_regular_expressions_from_lotusscript.html
or use LS2J
 https://openntf.org/main.nsf/project.xsp?r=project/Regular%20Expressions%20for%20LotusScript/